# How to save char field line by line using enter keyword into database using django models?

Tags: django

i want to save text field line by line into database using enter keyword. After writing some text if i press enter remainging text should save as next line. How to do this? someone help me.

I am using form in django. Form contains charfiled (Text area).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaces line breaks in plain text with appropriate HTML; a single newline becomes an HTML line break `(<br />)` and a new line followed by a blank line becomes a paragraph break `(</p>)`.

For example:

```
{{ value|linebreaks }}
```

Comment: Hi @Shiv. My code is like this {{ question.question|linebreaks }}. I incuded <br/> in text area field. Still i am not getting in html file. My html page showing <br/> tag also